# Import order in Python 3

Tags: python, python-import

I'm having a few issues with a number of imports in my program,

In main.py:

```
from world import *
from dialogue import *
from event import *
```

In dialogue.py:

```
from world import *
from event import *
```

The class Area is defined in world.py, yet when I try to use the Area class from dialogue.py it returns

```
builtins.NameError: name 'Area' is not defined
```

If I change the order of the imports in main.py to

```
from dialogue import *
from world import *
from event import *
```

When I try to access the dialogue class from world.py, I get this

```
builtins.NameError: name 'Dialogue' is not defined
```

I thought the order of imports shouldn't have made a difference? How can I access all of my classes from all of my files?

Comment: Importing * from many modules is probably a very bad idea

Comment: If you *must* access absolutely everything and don't want to list the things you need, you can consider simply `import world` and use `world.Area`, etc. @Bharel No "probably" about it. It's like.... the epitome of `import *` being a bad idea.

Comment: I agree with @Bharel.  You should try import world, etc. Can you post your code from world, dialogue and event?

Comment: You have namespace pollution, at least one name collision.  PEP008 says "*Wildcard imports ( from <module> import * ) should be avoided...*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The class Area is defined in world.py, yet when I try to use the Area class from dialogue.py it returns

The way you are importing your code is wrong. From both modules you are importing with `*`; this confuses the Python, because both modules have a class called `Area`.

Instead of using `*` (wild import) import them as modules

```
import dialogue
import world
import event

d1 = world.Dialogue()
d2 = dialogue.Dialogue()
```